# Update controller data on factory data is changed Angular

Tags: angularjs, factory

My modal have 'SelectBankModelCtrl' as controller.
'SelectBankList' is my factory

Here when I SelectBankList.loadBankList() call from controller if loads data from server but not updating the data object on datagrid.

Controller:
angular.module('sampleApp')
  .controller('SelectBankModelCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, items, SelectBankList) {

```
SelectBankList.loadBankList()
$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
   item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
   $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};



$scope.vm = {
   bankList: SelectBankList.bankListdata,
   bankListParams: SelectBankList.bankListParams,
   pageSizeRangeOptions: SelectBankList.pageSizeRangeOptions,
   pageSizeNumber: SelectBankList.pageSizeNumber
}


$scope.gridOptions = 
{ 
    data: 'vm.bankList',
    columnDefs: [{field:'bankName', displayName:'Bank', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'routingNumber', displayName:'Routing', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'address', displayName:'Adderess', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'city', displayName:'City', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'state', displayName:'State', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'zip', displayName:'Zip', enableCellEdit: false},
             {field:'phone', displayName:'Phone', enableCellEdit: false}]
};
```

==========================================================================
Service: 
angular.module('sampleApp')
  .factory('SelectBankList', function (Config, $window, $http, $log, transformRequestAsFormPost) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

```
var bankListdata = [{"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'},
       {"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'},
       {"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'},
       {"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'},
       {"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'},
       {"bankId": '', "bankName": '1ST CITIZENS BK AND TR COMPANY INC', "routingNumber": "53202266", "address": "1314 PARK STREET", "city": 'COLUMBIA', "state":'SC', "zip":'29201'}];
var pageSizeRangeOptions  = [
        {name: 20, value: 20},
        {name: 50, value: 50},
        {name: 100, value: 100}];
var pageSizeNumber = pageSizeRangeOptions[0];
var bankListParams = {
  access_token: $window.localStorage['token'],
  page:1,
  pageSize: pageSizeNumber.value,
  searchField: '',
  sort: ''
}

// Public API here
return {
    pageSizeRangeOptions: pageSizeRangeOptions,
    pageSizeNumber: pageSizeNumber,
    loadBankList : loadBankList,
    bankListdata: bankListdata,
    getBankList: function () {
      return bankListdata;
    },
    getBankListParams: function () {
      return bankListParams;
    },
    getPageSizeRangeOptions: function(){
      return pageSizeRangeOptions;
    },
    getPageSizeNumber: function(){
      return pageSizeNumber;
    }
};

function loadBankList() 
{
  //$log.log("bankListParams.pageSize:" + bankListParams.pageSize);
  var url = Config.getOAuthEndpoint() + '/bank/list';
     return $http({
        method: "GET",
        transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
        url : url,
        params : bankListParams
    }).then(handleBankListResult, handleBankListError);
}
function handleBankListResult (response){ 
     if(response){
       bankListdata = response.data.values;
       $log.log("Upadated List:"+ response.data.values[0].bankName);
       $log.log("Bank list: " + bankListdata[0].bankName); 
     }
}

function handleBankListError (response){ 

}
```

=========================================================================
Markup:

Show records per page

Comment: I dont see you catching data in success of your call back function. You will have to set data in your controller scope on the success of loadBankList()

Comment: Are you suggesting code in controller like below:
SelectBankList.loadBankList().then(function(){
      $scope.vm.bankList = SelectBankList.getBankList();
     });